# IOS UserDefault cannot be stored locally

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am new to programming and I am now working on an app that requires a login system. (A not so secure system). I wrote the following codes

```
@IBAction func CreateACPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if usernameTextField2.hasText && passswordTExtField2.hasText {

  let  newUser = accountInfo(username: usernameTextField2.text!, password: passswordTExtField2.text!)


    var randomTestingArr : NSArray = [accountInfo]() as NSArray

    randomTestingArr.adding(newUser)

   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   defaults.set(randomTestingArr, forKey: "ACArr")
   defaults.synchronize()

   let array = defaults.array(forKey: "ACArr")  as? [accountInfo] ?? [accountInfo]()

    for i in array{
        print("username: \(i.username) password: \(i.password)")
    }



    // temp retrieve
    }else {
        print("you havent entered anything")
    }

}
```

but when I hit the create button on my app, the console did not print out the username and password I entered.

what is the problem here?

Comment: You cannot save custom objects (`accountInfo`) in user defaults and your code will reliably crash if one of the text fields doesn't contain text.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to saving may be creating problem.

Instead of this

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 defaults.set(randomTestingArr, forKey: "ACArr")
 defaults.synchronize()
```

Replace with this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(usernameTextField2.text!, forKey: "UserName")
defaults.set(passswordTExtField2.text!, forKey: "Password")
defaults.synchronize()
```

And I am sure that it will works fine.

Comment: yea, I tried this before and it worked fine. But is there no way to save array containing structures?